# DOM Pdf is not working in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

public function reporting_page()
{

```
    $res=array();
    if ($this->input->post()) {
        $date1=$this->input->post('date1');
         
        $date2= $this->input->post('date2');

        $this->load->model('Investor_model');
        $res['idata']= $this->Investor_model->fetch_tranaction_report($date1, $date2);

        $this->load->view('investor/report', $res, true);
        echo '<h2>Test</h2>';
    
        $html = $this->output->get_output();
        // Load pdf library

        $this->load->library('pdf');
        $this->dompdf->loadHtml($html);
        $this->dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);
        $this->dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

        $this->dompdf->render();
        $output=$this->dompdf->stream("html_contents.pdf", array("Attachment"=> 0));
        

            } else {
        $this->load->view('investor/report', $res);
    }
}
```

It is giving errorA PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: 8192
> Message: Required parameter $dompdf follows optional parameter $paper
> Filename: Adapter/CPDF.php
> Line Number: 182

Backtrace:

```
File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 38
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 38
Function: require_once

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\CanvasFactory.php
Line: 57
Function: autoload

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php
Line: 299
Function: get_instance

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\Pdf.php
Line: 23
Function: __construct

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\controllers\Investor_controller.php
Line: 871
Function: library

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\index.php
Line: 291
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Required parameter $dompdf follows optional parameter $paper

Filename: src/Canvas.php

Line Number: 27

Backtrace:

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 38
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 38
Function: require_once

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Adapter\CPDF.php
Line: 37
Function: autoload

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 38
Function: require_once

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\CanvasFactory.php
Line: 57
Function: autoload

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php
Line: 299
Function: get_instance

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\Pdf.php
Line: 23
Function: __construct

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\controllers\Investor_controller.php
Line: 871
Function: library

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\index.php
Line: 291
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Required parameter $img follows optional parameter $w

Filename: lib/Cpdf.php

Line Number: 4728

Backtrace:

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 29
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 29
Function: require_once

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Adapter\CPDF.php
Line: 198
Function: autoload

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\CanvasFactory.php
Line: 57
Function: __construct

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php
Line: 299
Function: get_instance

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\Pdf.php
Line: 23
Function: __construct

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\controllers\Investor_controller.php
Line: 871
Function: library

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\index.php
Line: 291
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Required parameter $data follows optional parameter $w

Filename: lib/Cpdf.php

Line Number: 5071

Backtrace:

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 29
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 29
Function: require_once

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Adapter\CPDF.php
Line: 198
Function: autoload

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\CanvasFactory.php
Line: 57
Function: __construct

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php
Line: 299
Function: get_instance

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\Pdf.php
Line: 23
Function: __construct

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\controllers\Investor_controller.php
Line: 871
Function: library

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\index.php
Line: 291
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Required parameter $imageWidth follows optional parameter $w

Filename: lib/Cpdf.php

Line Number: 5415

Backtrace:

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 29
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 29
Function: require_once

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Adapter\CPDF.php
Line: 198
Function: autoload

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\CanvasFactory.php
Line: 57
Function: __construct

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php
Line: 299
Function: get_instance

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\Pdf.php
Line: 23
Function: __construct

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\controllers\Investor_controller.php
Line: 871
Function: library

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\index.php
Line: 291
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Required parameter $imageHeight follows optional parameter $w

Filename: lib/Cpdf.php

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 29
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 29
Function: require_once

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Adapter\CPDF.php
Line: 198
Function: autoload

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\CanvasFactory.php
Line: 57
Function: __construct

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php
Line: 299
Function: get_instance

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\Pdf.php
Line: 23
Function: __construct

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\controllers\Investor_controller.php
Line: 871
Function: library

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\index.php
Line: 291
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192

Message: Required parameter $imgname follows optional parameter $w

Filename: lib/Cpdf.php

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 29
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Autoloader.php
Line: 29
Function: require_once

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Adapter\CPDF.php
Line: 198
Function: autoload

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\CanvasFactory.php
Line: 57
Function: __construct

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php
Line: 299
Function: get_instance

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\libraries\Pdf.php
Line: 23
Function: __construct

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\controllers\Investor_controller.php
Line: 871
Function: library

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\index.php
Line: 291
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: require_once(dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: controllers/Investor_controller.php

Line Number: 876

Backtrace:

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\controllers\Investor_controller.php
Line: 876
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\controllers\Investor_controller.php
Line: 876
Function: require_once

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\index.php
Line: 291
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\system\core\Exceptions.php:271)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 570

Backtrace:

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Failed opening required 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php' (include_path='C:\custom\php\PEAR')

Filename: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\application\controllers\Investor_controller.php

Line Number: 876

Backtrace:

File: C:\custom\htdocs\iapp\index.php
Line: 291
Function: require_once
```

I also tried to install composer to resolve this error but not worked. please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Required parameter $xxx follows optional parameter $yyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65297279/required-parameter-xxx-follows-optional-parameter-yyy)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using old version of Dompdf. Upgrade your Dompdf as it has been [fixed](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2328).

See [commit](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/commit/6e48707d7b39140c4846477d5b7d26f486d1da06#diff-8cfe1d8c042ea6820be2187556a47e4092fd71e42854f0010a815370402a9db7) about this fixed on Adapter/CPDF.php.

See all releases https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases