# PHP: ArgumentCountError on method with optional parameter

Tags: php, php-8.1

PHP 8.1. I declared a method with this signature:

```
public static function if(mixed $condition, mixed $subject = null, \Closure $callback)
```

And called it with this call:

```
CLASS::if(condition: is_numeric(...), callback: do_something(...));
```

Yet I still got this exception:

> ArgumentCountError: CLASS::if(): Argument #2 ($subject) not passed

Why? `$subject` clearly is set to default to null.

Comment: [php function's required parameter confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10814149/2943403) and [Required parameter $xxx follows optional parameter $yyy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65297279/2943403)

Comment: Simple demo of breakge: https://3v4l.org/D4HhA and after fixing the method signature: https://3v4l.org/agWnE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `$callback` parameter has no default value, it's a required argument, and [so is every argument before it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-472). Therefore, `$subject = null` doesn't mean `null` is a default value; [it only means `$subject` is nullable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-481) (everything other than `null` would have triggered a deprecation notice).

To solve the problem, depending on the behaviour you're expecting, you can either place the `$subject` parameter at the end, or add a default value to the `$callback` parameter.

Comment: If you feel that one of the links that I commented is a suitable dupe target, please vote to close and transfer your advice there because https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.